# zdelta compression library segfaults

Tags: c, compression

I'm using zdelta library (http://cis.poly.edu/zdelta/) to compress a bunch of binary files and have been running into the issue where decompression almost always segfaults, even with the command line interface. Just wondering if anyone ran into this before? 
I did some error isolation: compression output with my code is same as what I got from CLI (command is `./zdc reference.bin fileToCompress.bin > compressedFile.bin.del`) so I assume compression works fine. The confusing part is say I use `A.bin` as reference and compress against itself, then everything works perfectly. As soon as I try a different file it segfaults (compress `B.bin` with `A.bin` being the reference, for example). Same with the decompression CLI.
Code for compression, `bufferIn` is the uncompressed data and `bufferOut` is an output buffer area which is large enough (ten times as input buffer, so even if the compression *grows* the file things should still work):

```
int rv = zd_compress(reference, refSize,
                     bufferIn, inputSize,
                     bufferOut, &outputSize);
```

Documentation for compress:

```
433 /* computes zdelta difference between target data and reference data
434  *
435  * INPUT:
436  * ref      pointer to reference data set
437  * rsize    size of reference data set
438  * tar      pointer to targeted data set
439  * tsize    size of targeted data set
440  * delta    pointer to delta buffer
441  *      the delta buffer IS allocated by the user
442  * *dsize   size of delta buffer
443  *
444  *
445  * OUTPUT parameters:
446  * delta    pointer to zdelta difference
447  * *dsize   size of zdelta difference
448  *
449  * zd_compress returns ZD_OK on success,
450  * ZD_MEM_ERROR if there was not enough memory,
451  * ZD_BUF_ERROR if there was not enough room in the output
452  * buffer.
453  */
454 ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT zd_compress OF ((const Bytef *ref, uLong rsize,
455                      const Bytef *tar, uLong tsize,
456                      Bytef *delta, uLongf* dsize));
```

==============================

Code for decompression, `bufferIn` is the compressed data and `bufferOut` is an output buffer area which is 1000 times than the input (bad practice yes, but I'd like to figure out the segfault first..):

```
int rv = zd_uncompress(reference, refSize,
                       bufferOut, &outputSize,
                       bufferIn, inputSize);
```

Documentation for uncompress:

```
518 /* rebuilds target data from reference data and zdelta difference
519  *
520  * INPUT:
521  * ref      pointer to reference data set
522  * rsize    size of reference data set
523  * tar      pointer to target buffer
524  *          this buffer IS allocated by the user
525  * tsize    size of target buffer
526  * delta    pointer to zdelta difference
527  * dsize    size of zdelta difference
528  *
529  *
530  * OUTPUT parameters:
531  * tar      pointer to recomputed target data
532  * *tsize   size of recomputed target data
533  *
534  * zd_uncompress returns ZD_OK on success,
535  * ZD_MEM_ERROR if there was not enough memory,
536  * ZD_BUF_ERROR if there was not enough room in the output
537  * buffer.
538  */
539 ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT zd_uncompress OF ((const Bytef *ref, uLong rsize,
540                        Bytef *tar, uLongf *tsize,
541                        const Bytef *delta, uLong dsize));
```

The size variables are all properly initialized. Whenever I run decompression it segfaults deep inside zdelta library at a `memcpy` in `zdelta/inffast.c`, seems like a bad destination (only except the case I mentioned above). Anyone had this issue before? Thanks!

Comment: Since you have the source code, I recommend that you recompile with debugging enabled and then run gdb against the program. That should pinpoint the segfault immediately (assuming it's not the type of bug that gets perturbed out of existence when debugging is turned on). Also, try Valgrind against a debug build in order to see if the probably is being naughty with memory.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I did resolve this problem, was (at least) an overflow problem in inffast.c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this problem was caused by a negation of an unsigned variable, in file inffast.c at line 138:

```
ptr = rwptr[best_ptr] + (sign == ZD_PLUS ? d : -d);
```

`d` is declared of type `uInt`, so the negation in the false part will (most likely) overflow, which was the cause of the bad destination address of `memcpy()`.

SImply changing this into:

```
if(ZD_PLUS == sign)
{
    ptr = rwptr[best_ptr] + d;
}
else
{
    ptr = rwptr[best_ptr] - d;
}
```

Resolves the issue.

Same story for line 257 in infcodes.c:

```
c->bp = rwptr[best_ptr] + (c->sign == ZD_PLUS ? c->dist : -c->dist);
```